# angular 6 filter the async pipe results

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I use angular 6 and I would like to filter the results of an async pipe, before rendering them in the UI.

Here is my code right now

```js
this.results = this.form.get('name').valueChanges.pipe(           
  filter(formdata => formdata.name.length > 0), 
  switchMap( formdata => this.service.getNames(formdata.name)) 
);
```

and the template

```html
  <div *ngIf='results | async ; let items'>
       <div *ngFor='let item of items'>{{item.id}} {{item.name}} </div>               
  </div>
```

From the pipe I get some ids and names. I already have an array of ids. I would like to filter the ids of the pipe and not render the ones that are already in the array.

So, here is what I try to do.

```js
array = [{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}];//I already have this
```

new version of filter in pipe

```js
this.results = this.form.get('name').valueChanges.pipe(           
  filter(formdata => formdata.name.length > 0), 
  switchMap( formdata => this.service.getNames(formdata.name)) ,
  filter(checkIfResultIdInArray())//pseudocode
);
```

Assume that `checkIfResultIdInArray` is I function I created. Filters and returns all the ids that are not in the `array`. So the ids/names that end up in the template are not the `{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}`.

Or maybe I can filter in the template somehow?

Comment: Instead of using the `Observable` filter function, you should use `map` in conjunction with the array `.filter` function instead

Comment: rxjs `filter` check if the event must be propagated. array `filter` filter the array (what you want). The rxjs `map` will propagate new value (you want to propagate the new filtered array). So like user184994 said, do an array filter into a rxjs map. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to do:

```js
this.results = this.form.get('name').valueChanges.pipe(           
  filter(formdata => formdata.name.length > 0), 
  switchMap( formdata => this.service.getNames(formdata.name)) ,
  map(names => names.filter(n => checkIfResultIdInArray(n)))
);
```

Typically, in a setup like this, i would also add a debounceTime operator to prevent too many requests.

Answer (score 10):

@Davy's answer is what I would do myself. However another option is to use a pipe. This is the way to go if you would like to reuse this functionality.

```js
@Pipe({name:'filterOnId'})
export class FilterOnIdPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(list : MyObject[], acceptedIds : number[]){
        return list.filter(item => acceptedIds.indexOf(item.id) > -1);
    }
}
```

and in the template

```html
<div *ngFor='let item of results | async | filterOnId : acceptedIds'>
    {{item.id}} {{item.name}} 
</div>
```

**Note the following:**

You use your custom pipe the same way you use built-in pipes.
You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule
If you choose to inject your pipe into a class, you must provide it in the providers array of your NgModule.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, you can replace `AsyncPipe` by a regular array, or alter the value of the emitted value (@Davy's solution is good).

There is however a template based solution. I'm putting it here for those who don't want to merge component's logic with view display.

**component**

```js
result$ = of([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); // for the sake of example

isAcceptedThing(thing){
  return thing%2 != 0 // accept only odd numbers
}
```

**template**

```html
<ul >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let thing of result$ | async">
    <li *ngIf="isAcceptedThing(thing)">
      filtered thing = {{ thing }} 
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**Output**

> > - filtered thing = 1
> > - filtered thing = 3
> > - filtered thing = 5
> > - filtered thing = 7

Comment: One can even do this only in template like `<li *ngIf="thing % 2 != 0">`. It may be easier for basic filter operations, but will become so messy for complex operations of course.